# MFMailComposeViewController navigationBar

Tags: ios, image, email, background

My app has a custom background for the navigation bar. So i made a category like this

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomImage)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"image.png"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}
@end
```

In my app I have to use MFMailComposeViewController. I create it like

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
```

But Apple's docs state that

> Important The mail composition interface itself is not customizable and must not be modified by your application. In addition, after presenting the interface, your application is not allowed to make further changes to the email content. The user may still edit the content using the interface, but programmatic changes are ignored. Thus, you must set the values of content fields before presenting the interface.

So this mean I can't keep my "image.png" as the navigation bar background for the mail composer view controller.

How one can accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the standard apple MFMailComposeViewController you can't, to put it simply. You would normally present it modally so it would go completely over your view anyway.

If you wanted a custom looking compose sheet, you would have to create it as a custom controller with a custom view. You would also need either a mail server built into your app, or a server that you can hit to send the mail for you.

For security reasons apple limit what you can do with MFMailComposeViewController.

If I can be of more help, please do ask :)

Comment: The "image.png" is on the mailComposer nav bar. I want to get rid of it

Comment: Sorry, I may have misunderstood that. So you already have it set on the controller..? If that's the case then yes you will have to stop doing it before you submit, as you will most likely get rejected. Though what I said about creating a custom one should still be valid.

Comment: Yeah, it really is. Looking back at the way you do it, you might get away with it. But it's up to you to decide if it is worth the risk. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: How do I change the category only for this screen?

Comment: Well, not very easily. In your category you should be able to get the navController for your navBar. Will be something like self.navigationController. Then you should be able to get the controller on top of the stack. Then check its class [self.navigationController.topViewController class] == [MFMailComposeViewController class] and if this is true don't set the image. Not the most elegant solution, but should do the job.